# IndexedDb get count spents 1 second. Any way to make faster?

Tags: indexeddb

I have an objectstore with 30000 entries with a 25000 bytes arraybuffer in each element.
Get the objectstore.count spents 1 second.  (between .count() and success event)

I have tried to make a readonly transaction with the same result.
Anybody have encounter the same problem? Any solution ? Save the value in some place? 
Thanks